# Angular CLI doesn't generate code for a downgraded module in production mode

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular-hybrid

I'd like to start using Angular components in an existing `angularjs` project would like to use `downgradeModule` to create a hybrid `Angular/AngularJS` app.

I've been able to downgrade my `angular` components using this code in the main.ts file:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { downgradeModule } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
import { AppModule } from '../new-app/src/app/app.module';

const bootstrapFn = (extraProviders: StaticProvider[]) => {
  const platformRef = platformBrowserDynamic(extraProviders);
  return platformRef.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
};

const downgradedModule = downgradeModule(bootstrapFn);

angular.module('old.angular.js.app', [..., downgradedModule])
```

While everything works fine when the `ng build` and `ng serve` commands are used, there is a problem with the prod mode - the compiled `js` code for `AppModule` is not generated when I run `ng build --prod` (I can't see it as part of the compiled `main.{hash}.js` file).

I suspect this is due to the fact that `AppModule` is bootstrapped on demand but I've no idea how to work around that and get this module to compile.

At the moment, I'm getting this error in my angularjs app since AppModule hasn't been compiled

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module old.angular.js.app due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module old.angular.js.app.newmodule due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'old.angular.js.app.newmodule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up adding a downgraded angular "bootstrapper" component to index.html whose only purpose is to make sure the new angular app gets bootstrapped as soon as possible.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
// This component is used to bootstrap the angular part of the application through index.html
@Component({
    selector: 'app-bootstrapper',
    template: ''
})
export class BootstrapperComponent { }
```

Index.html

```
<body>
    <div ui-view=""></div>
    <downgraded-bootstrapper></downgraded-bootstrapper>
</body>
```

angular-downgrades.ts;

```
angular.module('your-app')
    .directive('downgradedBootstrapper', downgradeComponent({ component: BootstrapperComponent }) as angular.IDirectiveFactory)
```

You may also need to tweak angular.json settings for production. We had to set `"optimization": false` in order to have our production build working (you can also try to set `"aot": false`).

Hope any of this helps.